# Rendering garbage in email client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, character-encoding, actionmailer

I'm having an encoding problems with Portuguese characters. It didn't render correctly.

This is replacing the Portuguese characters by ���

In my email method I have something like:

```
@html_content = html_content
@text_content = text_content

mail(
  :from => "#{from_name} <notifications@email.com>",
  :to => options[:recipients],
  :subject => options[:subject]
)
```

and in my views I have something like that:

```
<%= @html_content %>
```

I already checked the variable content and everything looks good. So probably the problem happens inside the method mail(...)

I tried to follow this instructions
[actionmailer encoding - rendering garbage in email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477739/actionmailer-encoding-rendering-garbage-in-email-client)

and didn't work. Any idea?

I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and Ruby 1.9.3

[UPDATE]

The bytes values are:

[208, 146, 209, 150, 209, 130, 208, 176, 208, 187, 209, 150, 208, 185]
[80, 111, 114, 116, 117, 103, 117, 195, 170, 115]

The message content is:

Віталій
Português

Comment: What are the actual byte values in the email message and what is its content-type and the charset attribute of that?

Comment: That probably won't work, but try to add `# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file, just in case.

Comment: The bytes are: [80, 111, 114, 116, 117, 103, 117, 195, 170, 115] and the charset is setted as utf-8